# tf.boolean_mask(2D, 2D) gives 1D result

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, mask, tensor

**The Issue**

[tf.boolean_mask()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) seems relatively simple: it removes values from a Tensor that don't match a condition. If the dimensions of the mask are the same as the target tensor, the condition works element-wise.

With `ret = tf.boolean_mask(src, mask)`, I find that the output dimensions do not match the input dimensions.

```
src:    Tensor("mul_3:0", shape=(?,?), dtype=int32)
mask:   Tensor("Cast_1:0", shape=(?,?), dtype=int32)
ret:    Tensor("boolean_mask/Gather:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)
```

Note that `(?,)` acts differently than `(?,?)`, although I'm not sure why or how.

---

**Code**

```
    src = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    src = tf.ones([tf.shape(src)[0], 1], tf.int32) * src

    matrix = tf.ones_like(src, tf.int32)
    matrix = tf.matrix_band_part(matrix, 3, 3) # number for mask is arbitrary
    mask = tf.cast(matrix, tf.bool)

    ret = tf.boolean_mask(tensor=src, mask=mask)
```

---

**What's the problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [*Returns* section in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask#returns):

> (N-K+1)-dimensional tensor populated by entries in tensor
>   corresponding to True values in mask.

where `N` is the dimension of `src` and `K` is the dimension of `mask`, when `N=K`, the return is always 1D, which is your case.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll accept this answer. Do you have any suggestions about how can I do what I'm trying to do (filter a 2D matrix based on a 2D mask)?

Comment: You can use a boolean mask to remove zeros from a 2D array, but there is no guarantee that the result is still 2D. For instance with `[[1,0],[2,3]]`, you will have `[1,2,3]` after zero removed but it won't fit as a 2D array or matrix.

Comment: Hm. How can I go from [[1,0],[2,3]] to [[1],[2,3]]? I tried using `tf.gather(src, tf.not_equal(src, 0)))`...does something like that work?

Comment: I doubt it whether you can have a tensor (which is usually squared) in that way. `tf.constant([[1],[2,3]])` gives an error for instance.